# Folder structure in express with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, backend

I'm starting with Express and TypeScript and I would like to know how is the folder structure to define the types in large projects.
For example, in Java projects, models and dto folders are usually created to define their entire structure. Can I follow this same structure in TypeScript or is there a better way?

I have searched and I see that a type.d.ts, type.ts or emun.ts file is usually created, others put users.interface.ts and it groups the entire structure here.

Comment: Are you looking specfically into express or generally into routers?

Comment: Or also into validation?

Comment: This is opinionated. But I use this structure for my project https://github.com/kennarddh/express-boilerplate.